# How to fetch images based on screen size

Tags: javascript

I have two different size background images based on a 500px break. I wish to preload the image that will be used based on screen size. I've tried this and it works.

```
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="/images/deckHomeSs.jpg">
```

Network tab on chrome tools says it started to download this first. Right answer.

I tried to dynamically decide which of two images to download using js in the head tag, and it works, but the network tab says it's the last thing it attempts to download.

```
<script>
    if (screen.width < 500) {
        document.writeln('<link rel="preload" as="image" href="/images/deckHomeSs.jpg">');
    }
    else {
        document.writeln('<link rel="preload" as="image" href="/images/deckHome.jpg">');
    }
 </script>
```

I thought js would execute immediately before doing anything else. So what am I missing?

Comment: Can you clarify (a) why you're using the outdated `document.writeln()` instead of properly adding your elements as child nodes to your DOM? (b) why you haven't elected to use something like `srcset` or `media` to conditionally preload these resources based on the width of the window?

Comment: I want the image to start loading asap because it's big and I read that this will increase page speed so i put it in the head tag.

Comment: Don't know srcset well, not sure if it would try to preload at the very beginning

Comment: background images and css with media queries are fine, and they will download the correct image based on screen width. But I want the correct image to start downloading right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to this design is to avoid using JavaScript for this task altogether (as there's no absolute guarantee when the JS will execute, as you've found) and instead opt to use more modern HTML features like the `link` element's [`media` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-media), which will effectively allow the browser to choose the file based on a media query (which I've included below to replicate the functionality you're attempting to achieve with `screen.width`):

```
<link rel="preload" href="/images/deckHome.jpg" as="image" media="(max-width:500px)" />
<link rel="preload" href="/images/deckHomeSs.jpg" as="image" media="(min-width:500.01px)" />
```

You can then use something like [`<picture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) to display it in your markup, based conditionally again on the width of the screen:

```
<picture>
    <source src="/images/deckHome.jpg" media="(max-width:500px)">
    <img src="/images/deckHomeSs.jpg">
</picture>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for in terms of the link tag. I don't see where the picture tag will tell it to start fetching before anything else. Anyway, it works perfect. Thx